# Linear independence of quasipolynomials

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Is the system of functions
$$e^{a_1x}x,e^{a_2x}x^2,\dots,e^{a_nx}x^n$$
linearly independent over the reals where each $a_i$ is real? If all the $a_i$'s are the same, then the linear independence is clear. However, I can't seem to prove the more general case or find a counter-example.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose
$$c_1e^{a_1x}x + c_2e^{a_2x}x^2 + \dots + c_ne^{a_nx}x^n = 0.$$
Taking the derivative of both sides and evaluating at $x = 0$ gives
$$c_1 = 0.$$
Thus
$$c_2e^{a_2x}x^2 + \dots + c_ne^{a_nx}x^n = 0.$$
Dividing both sides by $x$ gives
$$c_2e^{a_2x}x + \dots + c_ne^{a_nx}x^{n - 1} = 0.$$
An inductive argument gives $c_2 = \dots = c_{n} = 0$, so the claim is proved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Suppose no, then we can write
$$
C_1 e^{a_1 x}x+C_2 e^{a_2 x}x^2+\ldots+C_n e^{a_n x} x^n =0
$$
The function on the LHS is analytic, and so we can write it as a power series. It can be equal to zero only if all the coefficients in the series are. Let's look at the coefficient of $x$, it is $C_1$, thus $C_1=0$. Now we have
$$
C_2 e^{a_2 x}x^2+\ldots+C_n e^{a_n x} x^n =0
$$
Let's consider this away from zero and divide by $x$:
$$
C_2 e^{a_2 x}x+\ldots+C_n e^{a_n x} x^{n-1}=0
$$
Now we can repeat the procedure to see that $C_2=0$ and so on. Thus all the $C_i=0$ which means that these functions are independent.